# Want to bulk import from txt file into temporary table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I keep getting this error:

> Parse error at line: 1, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'BULK'.

The following is my text. I am now using a test file with two rows in the correct format so as to rule that out as causing an issue.

```
create table #tabled1
(
    vehicleid bigint,
    speed decimal(9,6),
    latitude decimal(9,6),
    longitude decimal(9,6),
    direction smallint,
    gpsquality tinyint
)
GO

BULK INSERT #tabled1
   FROM 'C:\Users\michael.mccarthy\documents\test.txt'
   WITH (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = '/t',
      rowtERMINATOR = '/n',
      KEEPNULLS
   );
GO
```

Comment: You're creating a temp table but trying to insert into a regular table.

Comment: Try: `BULK INSERT #tabled1` - you need that `#` before the table name!

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when copying over. that's not the issue. I've corrected in the query above now.

Comment: the line its referring to is correct its the line with bulk. i'm trying it in multiple places - sql server and visual studio. perhaps its a permissions issue? sounds like its expecting something in front of bulk though

Answer (score 2):

[user2772056](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2772056/user2772056) --
Although you probably resolved this long ago, you are using the incorrect slash. The separator character and the row-terminator should use a backslash "\", not a forward slash "/".  Try this--

```
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    rowtERMINATOR = '\n',
    KEEPNULLS
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query.

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(1000)
SET @Query ='BULK INSERT #tabled1  FROM "C:\Users\michael.mccarthy\documents\test.txt"
        WITH(   
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
            )'
EXEC (@Query)
SELECT * FROM #tabled1
```

Comment: I have tested this in my local environment, it is working fine, plz check your environment.

Comment: what should I be looking out for? to me I feel it is fine as well. is it a permissions issue? I am able to insert into temporary tables and i'm able to save to this location so I don't think it could be that

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2005?

Comment: sql server 2012